# Telethon doesn't allow a bot to join a channel (The method you tried to invoke cannot be executed as a bot (caused by JoinChannelRequest)

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

Im new with Telethon and I still have my doubts.

My task seems easy: I want to create a bot to **scrape** some info from a channel, but I got stuck in the first step: joining the bot to a chanel.

For to be sure Im doing it well I seek and find in [telethon.dev](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/channels/join_channel.html) page this piece of code Im trying:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

api_id = XXXXXXXXXXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
token= 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

with TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.channels.JoinChannelRequest(
        channel='publicchanel'
    ))
    print(result.stringify())
```

I also tried to log as a bot, using (of course, changing what it need to be changed/added):

```
bot = TelegramClient('bot', api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=token)
```

But I also got the same error:

> telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.BotMethodInvalidError: The API access
> for bot users is restricted. The method you tried to invoke cannot be
> executed as a bot (caused by JoinChannelRequest)

What am I doing wrong?

PD: If it matters: I'm using **Debian10** as OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bots connot join, sign in with bot in graph messenger and checkout how its working.
You should add bot to channel and give him admin permitions.
If you check the docs well you'll see that this joinchannel method is just for users.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a Telethon restriction, it's a Telegram restriction. Bots can't join groups or channels on their own and need to be added by a user.

Comment: That seems very reasonable... But, if I want to scrap data from a channel, how should I do? I know it can be done, because others bots do what Im trying to achieve. Can you guide me, please?

Comment: @k.Cyborg you need to add the bot manually. In channels, you also need to add it as an admin.

Comment: Still no way of doing this without being a channel admin ?